# Finding the nearest Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to build an android application to look for the nearest Bluetooth device, i am using the Bluetooth adapter with broadcast receiver to look for nearby devices and filtering the found devices based on their RSSI value. The problem that i am facing is it takes too long to discover the devices and if i try to run the discovery for a short amount of time it doesn't find all the devices that are necessary, for example if i have two devices and keep one of the devices near to my android mobile, sometimes it doesn't get detected but the one which is far from the mobile gets detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an asynchronous process managed entirely by Android. AFAIK, unfortunately, you cannot 'improve' it, or 'force' it anyhow (apart maybe from running as root and writing a BT stack yourself).

**UPDATE**: One thing that I didn't initially think of is to try toggling the Bluetooth functionality off/on.

```
private static BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = null;

// ..

void toggleRefreshBluetooth ()
{
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter ();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled ())
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable ();
    }
}


// ... in onCreate

btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver ()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent != null && BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals (intent.getAction ()))
        {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra (BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state)
                {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        // Bluetooth has been turned off
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable ();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        // Bluetooth is turning off
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        // Bluetooth has been on
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        // Bluetooth is turning on
                        break;
                }
         }
    }
};

final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter ();
filter.addAction (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver (btReceiver, filter);
```

Calling `toggleRefreshBluetooth` might force proper rescan. Give it a try, unless it's inconvenient in your circumstances.

It does not require the app to be a system app and you do not have to root the phone. The only thing you need is the `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission.

Comment: I wish there was a way, but thanx anyway.

Comment: I added a possible solution (possible workaround) to my post.